Peachpie on MacOS M CPU (ARM) Not Working
I installed .NET SDK 8.0,
macOS version is Sonoma.
I run the suggested example commands to build an example app.
dotnet new -i "Peachpie.Templates::*"
dotnet new web -lang PHP
dotnet run -p Server

But when I run the server, it gives those errors, and localhost not working.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.301/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(32,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/xxx/Server/Server.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.301/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(32,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp3.1' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [/Users/xxx/Server/Server.csproj]

